Client error when running OpenOSRS within IntelliJ
I am having an issue related to a Runescape Private server that I am working on. The OpenOSRS Kotlin>application>run is throwing 2 java.lang errors. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
The project is part of a larger issue I am trying to work through. The vision is to get the Runescape private server utilizing source: Kronos. This is a 317 revision loading OSRS content.
The dream is to get everything live hosted for my group of friends to play with the code and hopefully learn enough to start development off this release.
Client Screenshot
17:19:48,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:19:48,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
17:19:48,085 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/Codys/Desktop/Project%20Onyx/kronos-osrs-184-master/kronos-osrs-184-master/Kronos-master/runelite/runelite-client/build/resources/main/logback.xml]
17:19:48,134 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
17:19:48,138 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:19:48,139 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
17:19:48,142 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:19:48,167 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:19:48,171 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
17:19:48,180 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@966739377 - No compression will be used
17:19:48,181 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@966739377 - Will use the pattern C:/Users/Codys/.runelite/logs/client_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
17:19:48,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@38c6f217 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'C:/Users/Codys/.runelite/logs/client_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log'.
17:19:48,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@38c6f217 - Roll-over at midnight.
17:19:48,184 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@38c6f217 - Setting initial period to Wed Nov 20 02:16:56 EST 2024
17:19:48,184 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@38c6f217 - SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy instead
17:19:48,184 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@38c6f217 - For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
17:19:48,186 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:19:48,187 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: C:\Users\Codys/.runelite/logs/client.log
17:19:48,187 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [C:\Users\Codys/.runelite/logs/client.log]
17:19:48,187 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
17:19:48,188 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
17:19:48,188 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
17:19:48,188 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
17:19:48,188 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@478190fc - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

2024-11-20 17:19:49 [main] INFO  n.r.client.account.SessionManager - No session file exists
2024-11-20 17:19:49 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-2] WARN  net.runelite.client.game.ItemManager - Error fetching stats
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was NUMBER at line 1 column 64 path $.2.ge_limit
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
    at net.runelite.http.api.item.ItemClient.lambda$getStats$3(ItemClient.java:254)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:43)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was NUMBER at line 1 column 64 path $.2.ge_limit
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:790)
    at net.runelite.http.api.util.TypeAdapters$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was NUMBER at line 1 column 64 path $.2.ge_limit

    at net.runelite.http.api.util.TypeAdapters$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:47)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
2024-11-20 17:19:50 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] WARN  net.runelite.client.game.ItemManager - Error loading prices
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 57 path $[0].null
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
    at net.runelite.http.api.item.ItemClient.lambda$getPrices$2(ItemClient.java:215)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:43)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 57 path $[0].null
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 57 path $[0].null

    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:386)
    at net.runelite.http.api.util.TypeAdapters$3.read(TypeAdapters.java:199)
    at net.runelite.http.api.util.TypeAdapters$3.read(TypeAdapters.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
2024-11-20 17:19:50 [main] INFO  n.r.client.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin instantiation took 322ms
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.runelite.client.config.ConfigInvocationHandler (file:/C:/Users/Codys/Desktop/Project%20Onyx/kronos-osrs-184-master/kronos-osrs-184-master/Kronos-master/runelite/runelite-client/build/classes/java/main/) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.runelite.client.config.ConfigInvocationHandler
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.runelite.client.config.ConfigInvocationHandler (file:/C:/Users/Codys/Desktop/Project%20Onyx/kronos-osrs-184-master/kronos-osrs-184-master/Kronos-master/runelite/runelite-client/build/classes/java/main/) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.runelite.client.config.ConfigInvocationHandler

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

2024-11-20 17:19:50 [main] INFO  n.r.client.discord.DiscordService - Initializing Discord RPC service.
error_game_js5connect
2024-11-20 17:19:50 [main] INFO  net.runelite.client.RuneLite - Client initialization took 2628ms. Uptime: 2909ms
2024-11-20 17:19:50 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  net.runelite.client.ui.ClientUI - Showing frame net.runelite.client.ui.ContainableFrame[frame0,0,0,1920x1032,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Kronos,resizable,maximized,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,809x534,layout=org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstanceRootPaneUI$SubstanceRootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.border.SubstancePaneBorder@5c5284e7,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
2024-11-20 17:49:49 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-3] WARN  net.runelite.client.game.ItemManager - Error loading prices
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 57 path $[0].null
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
    at net.runelite.http.api.item.ItemClient.lambda$getPrices$2(ItemClient.java:215)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:43)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 57 path $[0].null
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:386)
    at net.runelite.http.api.util.TypeAdapters$3.read(TypeAdapters.java:199)
    at net.runelite.http.api.util.TypeAdapters$3.read(TypeAdapters.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 57 path $[0].null



the error message implies the JSON data it's loading (unsure where from) for prices is malformed, if this is a file you control, I would check the contents, it says line 1 column 64.
2024-11-20 17:19:50 [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1] WARN  net.runelite.client.game.ItemManager - Error loading prices
at net.runelite.http.api.item.ItemClient.lambda$getPrices$2 seems to imply it's fetching it via HTTP, so maybe the server isn't responding in the expected way anymore?
